# How to add task dependency on all test tasks in gradle in multi module project

Tags: gradle

I have java gradle project with multiple modules and each module has its tests. How can I configure gradle to run some task (run `docker compose up` to give you some context, but that's not a part of the question) before first test task is run and some another task after last test has finished?

Answer (score 2):

You can use both [`dependsOn`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#dependsOn(java.lang.Object...)) and [`finalizedBy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#finalizedBy(java.lang.Object...)) on all test tasks from the root project. If all tasks share a common base class (`Test` in this example), you can use [`withType`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskCollection.html#withType(java.lang.Class)):

```
subprojects*.tasks.withType(Test)*.configure {
    dependsOn myPreparationTask
    finalizedBy myCleanUpTask
}
```

If you need to configure tasks of different types, use the [`matching`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskCollection.html#matching(groovy.lang.Closure)) method instead with a custom condition.